# How to run WMI command on local system with elevated privileges from GPO login script?

Tags: windows-xp, wmi, administrator, wmic, gpo

I want to run WMI queries from a GPO deployed user login script to gather user information.

Problem is that [users must be a member of the administrators group to be able to run WMIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#account_needed_to_run_wmi_command-line_tools) and I can't give these specific domain users admin rights.

Is it possible to run WMIC with elevated privileges in a GPO login script on local Windows XP systems so that it will work when limited (non-admin) users login?

To clarify, this question is not about WMI connections to remote systems. It's about running WMIC on the system locally.

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting, good question. Unfortunately, the answer is "no, this cannot be done". The login scripts are always run with the user's credentials.

As a workaround, you could instead have the login script "notify" or flag a monitoring script that user X has logged in, which would then begin a reciprocal WMI session to the computer that the user logged into. Then WMIC would launch on management server with admin rights, and run against the host that just sent the login. Of course, WMI permissions get very picky, and you'll need to run them by setting `impersonationLevel=Impersonation` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use PowerShell?
Basic example that can be run from CMD:

```
powershell.exe -command "gwmi win32_userprofile"
```